# How to modify string in R taking into account the number of symbols you want to modify

Tags: regex, r

This question is very easy to understand, but I can't wrap my head around how to get a solution. Let's say I have a vector and I want to modify it so it would have 5 integers at the end, and missing digits are replaced with zeros:

```
Smth1     Smth00001
Smth22    Smth00022
Smth333   Smth00333
Smth4444  Smth04444
Smth55555 Smth55555
```

I guess it can be done with regex and functions like gsub, but don't understand how to take into account the length of the replaced string

Comment: not really, dww. One person proposed str_pad from stringr and it really solves the issue, though the person asked about smth else

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea using `stringi`:

```
v <- c("Smth1", "Smth22", "Smth333", "Smth4444", "Smth55555")

library(stringi)
d <- stri_extract(v, regex = "[:digit:]+")
a <- stri_extract(v, regex = "[:alpha:]+")
paste0(a, stri_pad_left(d, 5, "0"))
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "Smth00022" "Smth00333" "Smth04444" "Smth55555"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R.  Someone else can prettify the regex:

```
sprintf("%s%05d", gsub("^([^0-9]+)..*$", "\\1", x),
  as.numeric(gsub("^..*[^0-9]([0-9]+)$", "\\1", x)))

[1] "Smth00001" "Smth00022" "Smth00333" "Smth04444" "Smth55555"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple 1-line solution similar to [Zelazny's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38380018/3832970) but using a replace callback method inside a `gsubfn` using `gsubfn` library:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> v <- c("Smth1", "Smth22", "Smth333", "Smth4444", "Smth55555")
> gsubfn('[0-9]+$', ~ sprintf("%05d",as.numeric(x)), v)
[1] "Smth00001" "Smth00022" "Smth00333" "Smth04444" "Smth55555"
```

The regex `[0-9]+$` (see the [*regex demo*](https://regex101.com/r/dW0sW0/1)) matches 1 or more digits *at the end of the string only* due to the `$` anchor. The matched digits are passed to the callback (`~`) and `sprintf("%05d",as.numeric(x))` pads the number (parsed as a numeric with `as.numeric`) with zeros.

To only modify strings that have 1+ non-digit symbols at the start and then 1 or more digits up to the end, just use this PCRE-based `gsubfn`:

```
> gsubfn('^[^0-9]+\\K([0-9]+)$', ~ sprintf("%05d",as.numeric(x)), v, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Smth00001" "Smth00022" "Smth00333" "Smth04444" "Smth55555"
```

where

- `^` - start of string
- `[^0-9]+\\K` - matches 1+ non-digit symbols and `\K` will omit them
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 passed to the callback
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: FYI, this solution is the only one among those present that uses 1 regex match operation.

Comment: I don't know why we are all getting downvoted. Very elegant solution BTW +1

Answer (score -1):

Here a solution using the library `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

num <- str_extract(v, "[1-9]+")
padding <- 9 - nchar(num)
ouput <- paste0(str_extract(v, "[^0-9]+") %>% 
                str_pad(width = padding, side = c("right"), pad = "0"), num)
```

The output is:

```
"Smth00001" "Smth00022" "Smth00333" "Smth04444" "Smth55555"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
library(stringr)
paste0(str_extract(v,'\\D+'),str_pad(str_extract(v,'\\d+'),5,'left', '0'))
#[1] "Smth00001" "Smth00022" "Smth00333" "Smth04444" "Smth55555"
```

Comment: How is this any different from my solution with `stringi` ?